# Azure B2C Android login AppAuth demo - page refreshes instead of logging in and doesn't redirect to the app

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-b2c, appauth

The [OpenID AppAuth Demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-android-app/) for logging into Azure B2C for Android doesn't work. On the "Sign in with an existing account" page I type in my credentials and tap Sign In. If I use the wrong details I get an error, so I know I'm putting the right details in. I don't get any error, there's nothing in the logcat and can't set a breakpoint because it's delegated to a WebView and I can't control it.

Comment: Are you trying to say that when you put wrong details, you get an error as expected. When you put right details in, nothing happens? You are just stuck on the sign in page? Its not clear.... A fiddler trace could help determine whats happening.

Comment: @JasSuri exactly. When I put in the wrong details, I get an error, and when I put in the right details, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml and MsalActivity.cs for the right clientid. 
I've had the same problem and have been searching for days, finally found it in the video from Xamarin University: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_B7kN5TKqM&feature=youtu.be (at minute 34.00)

To be a bit more specific: The ClientID in the B2CConstant file has to be the same as the one in the AndroidManifest.xml (Your native client). 
The one in the MsalActivity.cs is ID from the web api.